# using regex OR to replace a character

Tags: regex

I have a regex which is searching for instances of either a whitespace or underscore, to replace it with a dash.

```
function spinalCase(str) {

var origSentence = str;

// case of camelCase
origSentence = origSentence.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');


// convert to lower case and remove whitespace or underscores for dashes
origSentence = origSentence.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"-");


return origSentence;
}


spinalCase('The_Andy_Griffith_Show');
```

I'm not sure how to add a logical 'OR' to the regex after the / /g, or if I need to make it into an 'if' statement, which seems bulky and awkward.
 Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use either a `|` or a character class:

```
.replace(/ |_/g,"-");
.replace(/[ _]/g,"-");
```

Character classes will match anything listed. Almost all characters inside this will be treated literal except for a few meta-characters, eg `^` at the start which will negate the match (works as a match everything but ...) and `a-b` which will make a change between `a` and `b`.

Might be more that I missed.

The `|` is the closest you will get to a logical or. `match 1|match 2`.

And combined (I assume we are all grownups, and I don't need to tell you, that it's bad practice to actually do this):

```
/(John|Thom)s[oe]n/
```

Which will match:

```
Johnson
Johnsen
Thomson
Thomsen
```